# Can't get .trigger('click'); working

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

I'm working on date-based trigger in php, and want to auto click a button with this code:

```
<?php
    $oldDate = metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Date')); 
    $latestDate = explode("/", $oldDate);
    $year = $latestDate[2];
    $month = $latestDate[1];
    $day = $latestDate[0];

    $newDate = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;

    $newestDate = new DateTime($newDate);
    echo $newestDate->format('jS M Y');

    $t = time();
    $nt = strtotime($newDate);

    if($nt <= $t){

    } else { 
    echo "<script> $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#gatemodal').trigger('click');

    });</script>";
    }

    ?>
```

but the trigger click event doesn't fire up. Don't have a clue where the fault is. I've tried changing the trigger line into this:

```
$('#gatemodal')[0].click();
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#gatemodal').trigger('click');
```

still not working.

Comment: Why `echo` the script tag with php?

Comment: show us the rendered html not the server side code

Comment: Where you have link to jQuery? What about error in console?

Comment: As per requested, here's the outputted html:
`<h2 class="object-date">

        24th Feb 2015
  <script> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#gatemodal').trigger('click');
});</script>
</h2>`

i'm trying to include a jQuery function in a php if else statement, as illustrated above. The logic is like this: if the object's date is same or less than today's date, do nothing, else, auto click this jQuery function.

For reference, i'm trying to call a jQuery remodal plugin [link]https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#readme and trying to think how to activate this plugin w/o manual click.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm echoing the script tag with php only if the conditions are correct. In other words, i'm using php if else statement as a conditional trigger for a jQuery event.

Answer (score 0):

On the echo part, set a variable and assign it (e.g. $fail='1'), then on your php file check whether $fail has been set and it is equal to one then have your script.

```
`<?php if (isset($fail)&& $fail=='1'){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#gatemodal').trigger('click');
});
</script>";
```

`